# Enabling fuzzy matching in helm-bibtex

Tags: helm, bibtex, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-matching, helm-bibtex

Is it possible to enable fuzzy matching in helm-bibtex?

The following example illustrates why it would be very useful to enable it.  Imagine that typing "sm" returns these two matches.

- Smith 2015
- Smith 2016

To choose between the two, the logical thing would be to type "sm 16".  But without fuzzy matching, helm-bibtex says that there are no matches.

Enabling global fuzzy matching in helm (`(setq helm-mode-fuzzy-match t)`) does not work for helm-bibtex.